# Springboot MySQL + Docker Access Denied Error

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

i've been struggling for a while trying to troubleshoot how to fix this error.

I have a Springboot and MySQL project im trying to dockerize, my MySQL container starts up fine and when checking the logs using **docker container logs mysql-standalone** , i don't get errors.

The issue is when I try **docker container logs springboot-docker** (My springboot image) , I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'demo'@'%' to database 'docker_demo'
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar!/:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
```

I have a **demo** MySQL instance I created instead of using the **root** instance.

I have tried logging into MySQL shell as root and Granting access to all databases within my **demo** MySQL instance but I still get the same error.

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'demo'@'localhost';`
`Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)`

---

Dockerfile

```
1 FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre
  2 ADD target/docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar springboot-mysql-docker.jar
  3 EXPOSE 8089
  4 ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","springboot-mysql-docker.jar"]
~
```

---

Docker images

[image: Docker images]

---

Docker ps -a

[image: Docker ps -a]

---

I've had plenty of errors but have seemed to fixed them , it seems like this is the last issue I need to fix to finally be able to run my project in a container.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with your grant statement.
You are granting permissions to demo user using the statement `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'demo'@'localhost';` So the privileges are applicable to demo user only when that user is connected through locally ie. connecting from the application on the same machine, **as specified by @'localhost'**

update your grant statement like this,  `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%';`

Comment: Will try that and get back to you.

Comment: Getting this error when trying to grant all. ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT

Comment: @ServletException https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322175/not-allowed-to-create-user-with-grant

Comment: Been googling for a while and can't find a working solution, always getting the same:

ERROR 1410 (42000): You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT, when trying to GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'demo'@'%';

Comment: @ServletException Did you try the above link that I've posted?

Comment: I have, doesnt work for me

Comment: @ServletException Instead of granting all privileges try giving specific and execute the command